# mysql replace add trailing slash to url

Tags: mysql, replace, trailing-slash

Im struggling with this problem for 3 days since i dont know any coding or regex of etc

i have a wp streaming site with iframe content, the iframe source already in https

now i want to migrate my streaming site to https
but when i try to do that, there a lot of movies that cant play, and after i checked, the problem is the iframe url

The movies works ok if the iframe has trailing slash
`https://example.com/embed/pMVg9liYw9gTvL7/`

but without trailing slash, the movies wont load
`https://example.com/embed/pMVg9liYw9gTvL7`

What i want to achieve is to add trailing slash at the end of iframe url from mysql.

please help
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Use concat(url, '/') in your select statement.

Comment: hi thanks for the replycan u please explain how to ? thanks

Comment: Can you show your table design ? What columns does it have? What field stores the URL ??

Comment: hi again, the table is wp_postmeta, 
metakey repeatable_fields, and this is inside meta value a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Server 1";s:6:"select";s:6:"iframe";s:6:"idioma";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:45:"https://klikfilm.stream/embed/eprN0P0NMh9E6PP";}}

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't like to answer questions that show no attempt, but this one is so simple that it's easier to answer than post complaints.

Use a simple `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET url = CONCAT(url, '/')
WHERE RIGHT(url, 1) != '/'
```

Replace `yourTable` and `url` with the name of your table and the column holding the iframe URL than needs to be fixed.